# Screen goes blank when TV goes off for some time

Tags: 12.04, xorg, intel-graphics, tv

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a Fujitsu Esprimo with Intel Graphic Card.
This computer is connected to a TV over DVI to the TV HDMI (DVI-HDMI Cable).
The TV goes off everyday from 7pm till 7am next day and weekends, from Friday 7am till Monday 7am.

It is been often that on Monday, when the TV goes on, that a black or blank screen is in place. We have been trying to parse the logs, debug the kernel but cant really find anything relevant.

This is what i got from the graphic card module

```
root@empfang:/# modinfo -p i915
invert_brightness:Invert backlight brightness (-1 force normal, 0 machine defaults, 1 force inversion), please report PCI device ID, subsystem vendor and subsystem device ID to dri-devel@lists.freedesktop.org, if your machine needs it. It will then be included in an upcoming module version. (int)
modeset:Use kernel modesetting [KMS] (0=DRM_I915_KMS from .config, 1=on, -1=force vga console preference [default]) (int)
fbpercrtc: (int)
panel_ignore_lid:Override lid status (0=autodetect [default], 1=lid open, -1=lid closed) (int)
powersave:Enable powersavings, fbc, downclocking, etc. (default: true) (int)
semaphores:Use semaphores for inter-ring sync (default: -1 (use per-chip defaults)) (int)
i915_enable_rc6:Enable power-saving render C-state 6 (default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int)
i915_enable_fbc:Enable frame buffer compression for power savings (default: -1 (use per-chip default)) (int)
lvds_downclock:Use panel (LVDS/eDP) downclocking for power savings (default: false) (int)
lvds_use_ssc:Use Spread Spectrum Clock with panels [LVDS/eDP] (default: auto from VBT) (int)
vbt_sdvo_panel_type:Override selection of SDVO panel mode in the VBT (default: auto) (int)
reset:Attempt GPU resets (default: true) (bool)
enable_hangcheck:Periodically check GPU activity for detecting hangs. WARNING: Disabling this can cause system wide hangs. (default: true) (bool)
disable_pch_pwm:disable PCH_PWM (default: -1 (auto)) (int)
root@empfang:/etc/default# grep -H '' /sys/module/i915/parameters/*
/sys/module/i915/parameters/disable_pch_pwm:-1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_hangcheck:Y
/sys/module/i915/parameters/fbpercrtc:0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_fbc:-1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_rc6:-1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/invert_brightness:0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_downclock:0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_use_ssc:-1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/modeset:-1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/panel_ignore_lid:0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave:0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/reset:Y
/sys/module/i915/parameters/semaphores:-1
```

We also already killed the gnome screensaver and added a line on its configuration (gnome-screensaver)

Also on the Xorg Monitor Configuration, i tried to force that there is no Stand by or offtime. I am not that Linux specialist and i dont know where should i research more for this.

```
10-monitor-conf
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "ServerLayout0"
    Option "StandbyTime" "0"
    Option "SuspendTime" "0"
    Option "OffTime" "0"
    Option "BlankTime" "0"
EndSection
```

Thanks in advance